# return the right month of a datetime when using Date.UTC conversion

Tags: javascript, symfony, date, datetime, twig

I am working with Symfony, doctrine, twig and highchart.js.

I need to create a chart with the js library and doctrine ORM data object.

See my controller here:

```
public function chartTestAction() {

    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $datasGraphique = $em->getRepository('mySpaceMyBundle:Graphique2')->findAll();

    return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:myFolder:chartTest.html.twig',
                         array('datasGraphique' => $datasGraphique)
                         );
}
```

So, my entity looks like this in table schema:

```
 ----------------
|Graphique entity|
|----------------|
|id              |
|consomation1    |
|consomation2    |
|consomation3    |
|dateIndex       |
|----------------|
```

For explanation, there are 3 linecharts in my graph, in my lineschart I need to set the dateIndex for each consomation like this [example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time).

In fact I have on xAxis datetime, hour per hour for a day, it's a regular interval. But I need to make on yAxis the parameter for xAxis for the datetime, in order to display correctly the linechart on the right dateIndex. That means, xAxis is fixed, hour per hour, but If I have a dateIndex on `2015-05-05 00:03:08`, the yAxis need to point on this date which not appear on xAxis fixed hour per hour.

This my twig view with the javascript part containing the series code for highchart.js:

```
series: [
    //consomation1
        {
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'spline',
            name: '{{consomation1Name}}',
            data: [{% for data in datasGraphique %}
                    [Date.UTC({{data.dateIndex|date("Y,m,d,H,i,s"")}}), {{data.consomation1}}],
                  {% endfor %}],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' kW'
            },

        },
        //consomation2
        {
            yAxis: 2,
            name: '{{consomation2Name}}' ,
            data: [{% for data in datasGraphique %}
                    [Date.UTC({{data.dateIndex|date('Y,m,d,H,i,s"', "Europe/Paris")}}), {{data.consomation2}}],
                  {% endfor %}],
            tooltip: {
              valueSuffix: ' kW'
            },

         },
        //consomation3
        {
            name: '{{consomation3Name}}' ,
            data: [{% for data in datasGraphique %}
                    [Date.UTC({{data.dateIndex|date("Y,m,d,H,i,s"")}}), {{data.consomation3}}],
                  {% endfor %}],
            type: 'spline',
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' °C'
            },
            dashStyle: 'shortdot',

        }
    ]
```

**The problem occured with the Date.UTC conversion.** Indeed, the js script returns me no error, it works well except for the datetime.
For example in my database, I have this field `2015-05-05 00:03:08` matching with **2015 for year, May for mounth, 5 for day 00:03:08 for hour:min:sec**. But In my highchart, after the date.UTC conversion it returns me this value for this date `2015, Jun, 5, 00:03:08` which is not matched with my real data, just for the month, because in UTC January = 0 and December = 11 instead of datetime where January = 1 and December = 12 .

Someone knows a solution?

I think first that I need to convert the datetime in unix timestamp in my dql query, but I know that doctrine doesn't support the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function conversion.

How can I proceed to have the right month, can I force this in javascrip?

this the code in my javascript for xAxis:

```
//xAxis setup to manage the chart
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%H:%M',
        },

        tickInterval: 3600 * 1000,
        title: {
            text: '<b>Heures journalière</b> '
        },
        crosshair: true,
        tickWidth: 1,
        gridLineWidth: 2
    }],
```

---

EDIT - trying with Date.parse()

I tried this solution:

```
{
    yAxis: 2,
    name: '{{consomation1Name}}' ,
    data: [{% for data in datasGraphique %}
            [Date.parse({{data.dateIndex|date("Y-m-d H:i:s")}}), {{data.consoECS}}],
          {% endfor %}],
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: ' kW'
    },
},
```

It returns me this with the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` :

```
data: [
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 00:03:08), 0], // the error occured on the first data render here
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 01:19:34), -2],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 02:44:16), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 03:18:19), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 04:24:06), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 05:12:44), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 06:55:08), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 07:26:08), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 08:32:05), 1],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 09:34:50), 2],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 10:42:16), 3],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 11:16:03), 3],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 12:27:07), 1],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 13:22:08), 1],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 14:18:51), 3],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 15:06:27), -1],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 16:40:00), 2],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 17:30:24), 1],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 18:36:24), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 19:43:57), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 20:32:41), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 21:28:29), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 22:37:14), 0],
  [Date.parse(2015-05-05 23:53:14), 0],
],
```

Comment: I think here is the problem: `date("m,d,Y,H,i,s")`. For `Date.UTC()` this is proper order of params: `Date.UTC(fullYear, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, ms)`. Of course month is in 0(Jan)-11(Dec) range.

Comment: @PawełFus I think the best solution is to convert my datetime datas into **Unix Timestamp** in a dql query, I don't find yet how to proceed with doctrine dql

Comment: @PawełFus Of course I follow your suggestion, follow the right properties for date.UTC. Like you said in your comment, indeed month is in 0(Jan)-11(Dec) range. So see my edit, now I have the right date, except for the month, because in UTC, month is in 0(Jan)-11(Dec) range

Comment: How about not using `Date.UTC()` but `Date.parse()` ? Like this: `Date.parse({{data.dateIndex|date("Y-m-d H:i:s"")}})` ?

Comment: @PawełFus I do not use date.parse because in highcharts.js datetime have to convert in date.UTC. I have still tried your suggestion, but the line charts are not displaying.

Comment: My bad in the code, there should be : `.. H:i:s"`, not doubled quotes. The idea is to return date string from your backend to the JS. Trust me, Date.UTC() and Date.parse() in your case will work the same way, just make proper format. Both of the methods returns timestamps. Also, don't forget to copy&paste errors from the JavasScript console.

Comment: @PawełFus sorry if I do not write the errors occured in the javascript console, but with Highchart.js, there is sometime no error returned. Thank you to help all the time when I ask something on stack.

Comment: When nothing is displayed, then most probably some coding error, easy to fix. If nothing displayed and no errors then it's strange. The idea from my side is to get generated this JS: `Date.parse("2015-05-05 00:03:08")`. That suppose to work without issues, until something else is broken.

Comment: @PawełFus this is what the console returns me in trying with **Date.parse method**: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Ok, so there is missing `)` after `Date.parse()`, or some missing `"`. Could you show **generated** part of the data?

Comment: @PawełFus see my edit, sorry If I am boring, it's the first time I use javascript and date.parse

Comment: Ok, the problem is date are not inside the quotes. Try this: `Date.parse('{{data.dateIndex|date("Y-m-d H:i:s")}}')`. Don't worry, we will pinpoint this soon ;)

Comment: @PawełFus, sorry for answer just today, I have a lot work. So I tried your suggestion with `Date.parse('{{data.dateIndex|date("Y-m-d H:i:s")}}')`, no error occured, even in the javascript console, but It do not render the line correctly, for the date **2015-05-05 00:03:08** it returns me `Monday, May, 4 22:03:08` on the graph. But the graph display well the line chart (spline).

Comment: Try to set `useUTC` to false, see: http://jsfiddle.net/4099kjzy/

Comment: @PawełFus you are my savior ! Just make an answer on this stack question, I set useUTC: false and It displays the right date with the right index and the right pointInterval. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tow things to make it work:

- set `useUTC` to false
- change format for dates and use `Date.parse()`: `Date.parse('{{data.dateIndex|date("Y-m-d H:i:s")}}')`

And working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4099kjzy/

Answer (score 0):

To use unix timestamp and avoid date format problem you can replace

```
[Date.UTC({{data.dateIndex|date("Y,m,d,H,i,s"")}})
```

by

```
[Date.UTC({{data.dateIndex.date("U") }})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already try your two suggestion. I f I use `[Date.UTC({{data.dateIndex.date("U") }})`, twig returns me an error like **Method "date" for object "DateTime" does not exist**, and If I use `[Date.UTC({{data.dateIndex.timestamp }})`, my line charts are not displaying at all.